# Ionic Cordova - undefined is not an object (self.fetch.bind)

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to make an ionic webdav app for Android and iOS.
So I installed the node module [webdav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav) and created a new login page. In my login.ts I added the module as follows:

```
import * as WebDAV from 'webdav';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

    cunstructor() {
        var webdav = WebDAV;  // On this code snippet the error appears
    }
}
```

When I try to access the module, I get the error

```
undefined is not an object (self.fetch.bind)
```

Here's a screenshot: [undefined is not an object (self.fetch.bind)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPdZv.png)

This error only appears on the iOS emulator, but not on Android.
Following I've already tried:

- Searched for same or similar problems
- Reinstalled all node_modules
- Reinstalled cordova plugins
- Import webdav Module with `require()`
- Removed all unnecessary pages in my project

Environment info:
Ionic:

- Ionic CLI: 4.1.2
- Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 3.9.2
- @ionic/app-scripts: 3.2.0

Cordova:

- Cordova CLI: 8.1.1
- Cordova Platforms: ios 4.5.5
- Cordova Plugins:

  - cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3
  - cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0
  - cordova-plugin-device
  - cordova-plugin-splashscreen
  - cordova-statusbar
  - cordova-whitelist

System:

- NodeJS: v8.12.0
- npm: 6.4.1
- OS: OS X El Capitan
- Xcode: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002

Does anyone know how I could fix this error?

**EDIT:**
I've found out, that the problem happens in node-fetch / browser.js:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = exports = self.fetch;

// Needed for TypeScript and Webpack
exports.default = self.fetch.bind(self);

exports.Headers = self.Headers;
exports.Request = self.Request;
exports.Response = self.Response;
```

I found some articles and issues on ReactNative Repo, etc.
But those workarounds didn't worked for me. Also comment everything didn't worked.

Maybe someone got an idea?